# Stays (more) fresh (for longer)

Tags: word-choice, comparatives

My wife just said "stays more fresh for longer", which sounded double to me. But I don't know how to actually say it without being double.

When you put something in the fridge it stays...

1. more fresh.
2. fresh for longer.
3. more fresh for longer.

The first sounds like it'll stay fresh forever, just a bit more fresh when kept in the fridge.
The second sounds to me like it's either fresh, or spoiled.
The third sounds double.

Which works best? (I'm probably just over-analyzing stuff.)

Comment: I would say (2) is the most idiomatic (where 'fresh' means 'in a condition suitable for eating'). If you want to use a comparative you can say 'fresher' rather than 'more fresh'.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you mean by "double." But this all depends on the source of the information. I'm *used to* the marketing term "fresher for longer," meaning that it actually *is* fresher and it lasts longer too. (Typically, this revolves around food or drink that has had some new kind of packaging used—but is also used in the context of laundry detergent, for instance.) Whether any of it is actually accurate isn't something you can necessarily believe.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting. You can do something (keep in fridge) to keep your food fresh for a longer period of time (extend the freshness). But you cannot make the food more fresh than it already is.

Comment: @satnam But you can make it comparatively fresher than it would have been if you hadn’t put it in the fridge. Both “it stays fresh (for) longer” and “it stays fresher (for) longer” sound perfectly normal to me. One just describes it absolutely (fresh = fixed state of edibility), the other relatively (fresher = more edible than it would have been outside the fridge).

Comment: Food A and B are fresh. I'd posit A&B cannot get fresher. If A is put in the fridge, while B is not, in a day A anb B will be less fresh than in the beginning, but A will be fresher than B. If A&B stay where they are, A will always be fresher than B. If a certain level of freshness is considered, A will stay above that level for longer. To say that A stays fresher longer - might mean fresher **for** longer, which is double, or it might mean it stays fresher **and** longer, which is true, as decay will end the existence of A later than that of B.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "stays fresher for longer". The unspoken but inferred rest of this sentence is *...than if kept out of the fridge.* *Fresher* is being used comparatively.